# JMSSerializerBundle - continue deserialization in the custom handler

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have a custom handler that performs deserialization of my object:

```
public function deserialize(   JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor,
                               $data,
                               array $type,
                               DeserializationContext $context)
```

I don't want to take all deserialization job on my own, I only want to do some of that. For example, I have an Album (id, name, description, photos) and I want to deserialize "description" by myself, and left all other job to the bundle.

```
    if (!empty($data['id']))
        $album = $albumManager->createWithId($data['id']);
    else
        $album = $albumManager->create();

    $album->setDescription($albumDescriptionParser->parse($data['description']));

    // and now I want to delegate other deserialization job to JMSSerializer
    // ....

    return $album;
```

I know this is done using context, visitor and navigator, but I cant figure how

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the way to implement that. It seems it cannot be easy handled in the deserialization handler.

Instead, I used my custom `ObjectConstructorInterface` interface implementation and `serializer.post_deserialize` event.

Creation process can be handled in the custom `ObjectConstructorInterface` implementation and all "extra settings" can be set after deserialization actually done - when `serializer.post_deserialize` event occur.